# PHP & JS | div onclick play sound and change background

Tags: javascript, php

I have a list of divs, i want that every clicked div will:
play sound &
Change it's color for 3 secs.

My code
**Sounds:**

```
<?php  
$x = 1;
while($x <= 24) {
  echo "<audio id='$x' src='samples/s$x.wav'></audio>";
  $x++;
} 
?>
```

**Divs:**

```
<?php  
$x = 1;
echo "<tr>";
while($x <= 24) {
  echo "<div id='lupad' onclick='style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000"; setTimeout(function(){style.backgroundColor = '#000000';}, 320); document.getElementById('$x').play()'>$x</div>";
  $x++;
} 
?>
```

The function works with html but not with php.
**Thanks**

Comment: I think you have to write `this.style.backgroundColor`. But I highly recommend you to move the js code to a separate function, like `<div id='lupad' onclick='lupadClicked(this);'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script function show that call so your problem is solved.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <title></title>

   <script type="text/javascript">


      function show(x){

        //alert(x);
        var colors = ['red','blue','green']; 
        //alert(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);

        $('#lupad_'+x).css('background-color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#lupad_'+x).css('background-color','blue');
        }, 320); 
        document.getElementById(x).play();
      }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>


 <?php  
 $x = 1;
 while($x <= 24) {
  echo "<audio id='$x' src='samples/s$x.wav'></audio><br/>";
 $x++;
} 
?>

    <?php  
   $x = 1;
   while($x <= 24) {
   echo "<div id='lupad_".$x."' onclick='show(\"".$x."\")'>".$x."
  </div>";

  $x++;
 } 
 ?>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Hey are you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error with your syntax.
Your double quotes have double quotes inside.
You can add a backslash before the double quotes of the background color in order to make it work.

```
<?php  
$x = 1;
echo "<tr>";
while($x <= 24) {
  echo "<div id='lupad' onclick='style.backgroundColor = \"#FF0000\"; setTimeout(function(){style.backgroundColor = \"#000000\";}, 320); document.getElementById(\"$x\").play()'>$x</div>";
  $x++;
} 
?>
```

בהצלחה

Comment: That's still not working. The div doesn't react to the click

Comment: haven't noticed the rest quotes problems. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

please check this code

```
<?php  
 $x = 1;
 while($x <= 24) {
  echo "<div id='lupad' onclick='style.backgroundColor = 
  ".'"'."#FF0000".'"'.";setTimeout(function(){style.backgroundColor = 
  ".'"'."#000000".'"'.";}, 320); 
  document.getElementById(".$x.").play()'>".$x."
 </div>";
 $x++; 
}  
?>
```

Comment: Great! but i can't set the old background color after the timeout :O

Comment: which bg color that you want after the timeout tell me i can help you.

Comment: the div background color is #afc4ff. i want it to change to random ( colors[Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1)] ) and after 2 secs set back to #afc4ff.
Thanks Mate